# pthread_cond_wait and pthread_mutex_lock doesnt work as expected

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, threadpool

I've created a ThreadPool class, and void function called `execute_thread_helper()` which is called inside `void* execute_thread(void* arg)` (its a function given to a thread this way : `ret = pthread_create(&workers[i], NULL, execute_thread, (void*)this);`)

```
void ThreadPool::execute_thread_helper()
{
    Task task;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    while(TaskList.empty()) // Previously "if"
    {
        cout << "Thread #"  << pthread_self() << " is blocked. "<< endl;
        pthread_cond_wait(&conditionVar, &mutex);
    }

    task = TaskList.front();
    TaskList.pop();

    cout << "Thread #"  << pthread_self() << " going to run the function. "<< endl;

    threadFunction(task);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Tasks are added this way to a queue of tasks -

```
void ThreadPool::add_task(Task newTask)
{    
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    TaskList.push(newTask);    
    pthread_cond_signal(&conditionVar); 

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

}
```

As far as i understand, as soon as a thread will be created - it'll try to run `execute_thread`. And then, given an empty queue, i expect `pthread_cond_wait` "put" the thread to sleep (and do it to all created threads) until it will be awaken by `pthread_cond_signal` in `add_task`.

Well..i tried checking the program on a single thread, and got this result (i havent `add_task`. just tried to create the pool) -

```
Thread #139859560904448 is blocked. 
Thread #139859560904448 going to run the function. 
in map() key is   and value is 0
```

I don't understand how the thread passed the if statement , if it was put on hold previously .

output on trying to create 3 thread pool -

```
Thread #140013458028288 is blocked. 
Thread #140013458028288 going to run the function. 
in map() key is   and value is 0 
Thread #140013458028288 going to run the function. 
in map() key is   and value is 0 
Thread #140013458028288 going to run the function. 
in map() key is   and value is 0
```

Why aren't the other 2 threads put on hold?

**EDIT**

Thanks to SergeyA, switching the if with while, did help.
But still, trying to make 3 thread pool, results in this -

```
Thread #139916558706432 is blocked. 
Thread #139916558706432 is blocked. 
Thread #139916558706432 is blocked. 
Thread #139916558706432 is blocked. 
Thread #139916558706432 is blocked. 
Thread #139916558706432 is blocked. 
Thread #139916558706432 is blocked. 
Thread #139916558706432 is blocked.
```

Why no other threads are created? arent they all supposed to be created, run concurrently  and alternately print that they are blocked?

Comment: `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); //mutex lock` - why not `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); //pthread_mutex_lock`? Would make the code much clearer in the latter form, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Condition variables are prone to so-called *spurios wake-ups`. It means that the code is unblocked, but condition didn't really change and it was not signalled.

This is why you always have to call the `wait` function in a loop, and check the condition after every wake-up.

Answer (score 0):

`pthread_cond_signal(&conditionVar);` will only wake up *one* of the waiting threads. If your tasks are short enough you will by chance always wake up the same thread. There is no fairness. :-)

You can also wake up all waiting threads by using `pthread_cond_broadcast(&conditionVar);`. Then you should see all your threads always being woken up. But for your thread pool is should not be necessary to use the broadcast variant.